# Error when inserting CTE table values into physical table

Tags: insert, teradata, common-table-expression

I have a complex query that creates a master CTE_Table form other CTE_Tables.  I want to insert the results of the master CTE_Table  into a physical table.  I'm using Teradata version 15.10.04.03

SELECT Failed.  [3707] Syntax error, expected something like a 'SELECT' keyword or '(' or a 'TRANSACTIONTIME' keyword or a 'VALIDTIME' keyword between ')' and the 'INSERT' keyword.

DROP TABLE dbname.physicalTablename ;

CREATE MULTISET TABLE dbname.physicalTablename ,
     NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      col1 INTEGER,
      col2 INTEGER,
      col3 INTEGER
      )
NO PRIMARY INDEX ;

WITH

cteTable3 AS
(  SELECT  A.colA, A.colB, A.colC, B.col1, B.col2, B.col3
   FROM cteTable1 A INNER JOIN cteTable2 ON (blah blah blah) ),

cteTable2 AS
( SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM SourceTableB ),

cteTable1 AS
( SELECT colA, colB, colC FROM SourceTableA )

INSERT INTO  dbname.physicalTablename
( col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 )
SELECT 
(C3.colA, C3.colB, C3.colC, C3.col1, C3.col2, C3.col3)
FROM cteTable3 C3  ;

Comment: I don't see an `INSERT` keyword in your code. Did you share the wrong thing?

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing my question  when you responded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are missing the INSERT portion of the question, I think the following might clear things up. The correct format for using a CTE in an INSERT is:

```
INSERT INTO <tablename>
WITH <cte> AS (SELECT...)
SELECT <fields> FROM <cte>
```

Consider the following:

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE tmp AS (SELECT 'bobby' as firstname) WITH DATA ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO tmp
WITH cte AS (select 'carol' as firstname)
SELECT * FROM cte;

SELECT * FROM tmp;

DROP TABLE tmp;
```

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing my question  - - you guys are fast

Comment: I see my error -  I needed to inline the CTE scripting within the insert statement

Comment: I put two and two together and figured out where you were probably having the problem, since I've struggled with that one too in the past. I'm still surprised to this day that you can use a CTE with an INSERT, even if it does feel syntactically backwards.