# Create Table by Inserting Data from Select Statement created by With Statement

Tags: sql, teradata, create-table, with-statement

I have a pretty complex with statement that combines a lot of information to grab with a select statement in teradata studio. The with statement works wonderfully and selects the data I need, but I can't figure out how to create a view out of it, or save it as a persistent table, or do anything with it that would make it a persistent way to select the data. I want to use this with statement to save the select statement as a persistent table that I can then pull from using tpt scripts in an ec2 instance.

I used to create volatile tables instead of using a with statement and I could create the table by doing the correct select and insert statement. However, this is going to be put into a production environment and scheduled, and they weren't ok with that and said to wrap it up in a with statement.

I've tried wrapping the entire with statement into a create table or create view statement. I've tried changing the select statement that grabs the data and turning that into a create table or insert into statement, but none of these seem to cooperate with the with statement syntax.

```
WITH
customer_month_ad AS
(

),

months_since_last_payment AS
(

),

customer_month_2 AS
(

),

customer_month AS
(

),

date_things AS
(

),


network AS
(

),

skeleton AS
(

),

customer_stuff AS
(

),

customer_keyz AS
(

),

customer_activity AS
(

),

order_date AS (

),

months AS
(

)--,

SELECT *
FROM customer_month_ad
;
```

I want to save the output from the select statement into a persistent table.

Comment: Instead of just `select * from...`, you would use `insert into <your actual table>`, or a `create table as select` kind of thing.

Comment: See: [error-when-inserting-cte-table-values-into-physical-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305853/error-when-inserting-cte-table-values-into-physical-table)

Comment: Whatis your Teradata release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

`create table <your_table_name> as select * from <table_names>`

OR

`create table <your_table_name> as <your_select_statement>`

Replace:

`<your_table_name>` by the name of the resultant table

`<table_names>` by the names of the table from where data is coming

`<your_select_statement>` by the select statement if you have a different one which is

not like `select * from .......`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to do. I've got a spool space error now, but I can work with that.

create table table1 as (

with statement

select statement)
with data
;